# How can I serialize multiple numpy views (i.e. arrays with shared data) without duplicating the underlying data?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, serialization, pickle

I find cPickle duplicates the shared data when saving multiple numpy views on the same data.

For example:

```
import cPickle
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(1000000)
b = [a[i:] for i in range(100)]
with open('C:/temp/b.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    cPickle.dump(b, f, protocol=1)
```

This generates a 400MB file which implies cPickle is duplicating the buffer which is shared by all the views in list b (otherwise it would be around 4MB).

I want to be able to serialize without duplicating the data so that (a) the file size is smaller and (b) when I deserialize I restore the shared data status of the views.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You tell it to save `b`, which is a list `[a[i:] for i in range(100)]`.  The pickle method for a list iterates through the list and calls pickle for each element.  Each `a[i:]` is a different `numpy` array; each is a view, sharing the underlying data buffer of `a`, but the metadata, things like shape, strides and dtype are different.  So each list element (array) will be pickled without 'knowledge' of what has been saved before.

If you want it to save the list more compactly, you will need to create a class with its own pickle method.  That method can operate with the knowledge that those `a[...]` share an underlying data buffer.  Or maybe it would save `a` and the data needed to recreate this list.

In short, your pickled variable is large because the pickling method does not know anything about the deep structure of the list.

Answer (score 0):

When you serialize a view, it's always going to make a copy of your data.

A much simpler approach would be to serialize the inital dataset as well as the function used to produce the views. Then on load, apply this function to the stored data in order to get the different views.

Also instead of pickling, you should probably use the native `np.save`/`np.load` mechanism.